# AngularJS jsfiddle $http echo not returning data

Tags: angularjs, jsfiddle

I encountered a bug in a square-connect API wrapper for node, and I made a fiddle to recreate the issue. I noticed my code wasn't working, in the sense that angular {{}} stuff isn't showing up. What's wrong with it?

the only thing I'm trying to do is have the raw JSON object (preferably {{res}}, but it doesn't matter really) shown below the create button. I am just trying to demonstrate to the author of a library that my object and data is valid, and that a bug is in his library, not my implementation.

```
    var httpRequest = $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/echo/json/',
        data: item
    }).success(function(data, status) {
        $scope.res = data;
    }).failure(function(data, status){
        $scope.res = data+status;
    });
```

`data` is not being returned from jsfiddle's ECHO.

http://jsfiddle.net/efjytg6r/2/

Comment: I suggest you say what's wrong with it. How do you know it's not working properly? And lots more details. Don't just paste a fiddle and ask what's wrong with it.

Comment: @DanMoldovan apologies. I've been working on implementing a POS for my company for the past 18 hours and, again, making this to demonstrate a bug in an API wrapper. a bit tired and in a massive rush to have this problem resolved.

Comment: note: i have flagged this question by a moderator. downvote away, as it is earned and i knowingly violated the rules of stackoverflow. was in a mega time crunch and needed to get this figured out quickly. sorry guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close, but since you're saving your `$http` in a variable, you access the methods within it **using that variable**. (ie: `httpRequest.success` / etc)

Also it's **`.error()`** not *`.failure()`*

```
    var httpRequest = $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/echo/json/',
        data: item
    });

    httpRequest.success(function(data, status) {
        $scope.res = data;
    });

    httpRequest.error(function(data, status){
        $scope.res = data+status;
    });
```

jsFiddle is finicy with it's echo AJAX examples. You need to format what you send to them correctly with `json`, have it stringified as well as use jQuery's `$.param` (since angular doesn't do POST like you're used to with jQuery).

- I included jQuery to the fiddle below.
- I formatted the data being sent differently
- I moved your `{{ res }}` inside of the controller area (you had it outside, which means it won't compute)
- I added `| json` filter to `{{ res | json }}`

[Updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/efjytg6r/5/)

```
    // the wacky format you need if you want to do fake $http to jsFiddle
    // case in point, if you're trying to DEMO this, I wouldn't even bother, since it won't look like this when you actually use this within your application

    var data = $.param({
        json: JSON.stringify({
            item
        })
    });

    $http.post("/echo/json/", data)
            .success(function(data, status) {
                $scope.res = data;
            }).error(function (status) {

            });
```

Comment: sorry, read my comment in the original question. i needed much more clarification. i only am trying to show the raw JSON object to demonstrate my model that is being sent to a server (this is a modified version of my code that interacts with my own backend) is correct and that the bug I am trying to point out is in the library I am using. Again, this fiddle is only to demonstrate the problem is NOT In my client, and the problem I am asking about in this question is why I am not seeing whats in my {{}} below the create button

Comment: Just log your `item` to the console then, don't put it within the `success` or anything like that. jsFiddle's echo example might have issues with angularJS and doing this fake AJAX request. To demo it capturing the whole model, on your button click just do a quick `console.log( item );` instead, it'll prove the point that it's "sending" the whole object!

Comment: @h3xc0ntr0l Updated my answer, it now has the ability to send fake AJAX correctly to jsfiddle. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using `$httpParamSerializer` and a delay.

```
angular.module('myApp',[]);

angular.module('myApp').controller('myVm',
  function($scope,$http,$httpParamSerializer) {
    var vm = $scope;
    var xitem = {a:"1",b:"2"};
    var data = $httpParamSerializer({
        json: xitem,
        delay: 6
    });
    console.log("Posting xitem");
    vm.p = $http.post('/echo/json/',data);
    vm.p.then (function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        console.log(response.data)
    })
});
```